# Remote Video Element shows nothing in webrtc

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am new to WebRTC, I want to setup a video call by using web socket over node.js,I am Unable Display the Remote video screen but local video element works fine.

May be I am missing the flow which i could not figure it out.

I am posting my html code with java script here.

HTML Code

```
  <!---display sharing screen--->
<div id="video_container" style="display:none;">
This Streams Remote Video
  <video  controls autoplay id="remotevideo"></video><br>
This Streams Local Video
  <video controls autoplay id="local_video"></video>

</div>
```

The below is my javascript

```
var webrtc_capable = true;
var rtc_peer_connection = null;
var rtc_session_description = null;
var get_user_media = null;
var connect_stream_to_src = null;
var stun_server = "stun.l.google.com:19302";

if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // WebRTC 1.0 standard compliant browser
  rtc_peer_connection = RTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.getUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
  media_element.srcObject = media_stream;
  media_element.play();
  };
} else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // early firefox webrtc implementation
  rtc_peer_connection = mozRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = mozRTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.mozGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.mozSrcObject = media_stream;
    media_element.play();
  };
  stun_server = "74.125.31.127:19302";
} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // early webkit webrtc implementation
  rtc_peer_connection = webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.src = URL.createObjectURL(media_stream);
  };
} else {
  alert("This browser does not support WebRTC - visit WebRTC.org for more info");
  webrtc_capable = false;
}
</script>

<!---Javascript for splitting screen--->
<script>
function splitScreen()
{
  var z;
  document.getElementById("chat").style.display="block";
  z=document.getElementById("video_container");
  z.className="videoContainer";
  z.style.display="block";
}

 var call_token; // unique token for this call
 var signaling_server; // signaling server for this call
 var local_peer_connection;
 //function to establish webrtc connection
function start(){

    peer_connection=new rtc_peer_connection({ // RTCPeerConnection configuration 
    "iceServers": [ // information about ice servers
      { "url": "stun:"+stun_server }, // stun server info
    ]
  });
  setup_video();
    peer_connection.onicecandidate== function (ice_event) {
    if (ice_event.candidate) {
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type: "new_ice_candidate",
          candidate: ice_event.candidate ,
        })
      );
    }
  };
   peer_connection.onaddstream=function(event){
       //alert("remote video is getting called!!");
       connect_stream_to_src(event.stream,document.getElementById("remotevideo"));
   };

   signaling_server = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3455");

   if (document.location.hash === "" || document.location.hash === undefined) { // you are the Caller

    // create the unique token for this call 
    var token = Date.now()+"-"+Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
    call_token = "#"+token;

    // set location.hash to the unique token for this call
    document.location.hash = token;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {
      // setup caller signal handler
      signaling_server.onmessage = caller_signal_handler;

      // tell the signaling server you have joined the call 
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Caller";
    //document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "Ready for a call...ask your friend to visit:<br/><br/>"+document.location;

  } else { // you have a hash fragment so you must be the Callee 

    // get the unique token for this call from location.hash
    call_token = document.location.hash;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {
      // setup caller signal handler
      signaling_server.onmessage = callee_signal_handler;

      // tell the signaling server you have joined the call 
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );

      // let the caller know you have arrived so they can start the call
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"callee_arrived",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Callee";
   // document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "One moment please...connecting your call...";
  }

  // setup message bar handlers
  document.getElementById("message_input").onkeydown = send_chat_message;
  document.getElementById("message_input").onfocus = function() { this.value = ""; }
}

/* functions used above are defined below */

// handler to process new descriptions
function new_description_created(description) {
  peer_connection.setLocalDescription(
    description, 
    function () {
         //  connect_stream_to_src(event.stream,document.getElementById("remotevideo"));
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type:"new_description",
          sdp:description 
        })
      );
    }, 
    log_error
  );
}

// handle signals as a caller
function caller_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "callee_arrived") {
    peer_connection.createOffer(
      new_description_created, 
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate)
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {
         peer_connection.addStream(remotevideo);
          connect_stream_to_src(event.stream, document.getElementById("remotevideo"));
        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "answer") {
          // extend with your own custom answer handling here
          //connect_stream_to_src(remotevideo, document.getElementById("remotevideo"));
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_chat_message") {
    add_chat_message(signal);
  } else {
    // extend with your own signal types here
  }
}

// handle signals as a callee
function callee_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate)
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {

        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "offer") {
          peer_connection.createAnswer(new_description_created, log_error);
          connect_stream_to_src(event.stream, document.getElementById("remotevideo"));
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_chat_message") {
    add_chat_message(signal);
  }
}

// add new chat message to messages list
function add_chat_message(signal) {
  var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  var user = signal.user || "them"; 
  messages.innerHTML = user+": "+signal.message+"<br/>\n"+messages.innerHTML;
}

// send new chat message to the other browser
function send_chat_message(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) 
  {
    var new_message = this.value;
    this.value = ""; 
    signaling_server.send(
      JSON.stringify(
      {
        token:call_token,
        type: "new_chat_message",
        message: new_message 
      })
    );
    add_chat_message({ user: "you", message: new_message }); 
  }
}

function setup_video()
{//alert("In setup_video function");
   get_user_media({
      "audio":true,
      "video":true
   },
   function (local_stream) { // success callback
      // display preview from the local camera & microphone using local <video> MediaElement
      connect_stream_to_src(local_stream, document.getElementById("local_video"));
      // add local camera stream to peer_connection ready to be sent to the remote peer
      peer_connection.addStream(local_stream);
    },
    log_error
  );
}


// generic error handler
function log_error(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Server.js

```
// useful libs
var http = require("http");
var fs=require("fs");
var websocket = require("websocket").server;

// general variables
var port = 3455;
var webrtc_clients = [];
var webrtc_discussions = {};

// web server functions
var http_server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var matches = undefined;
  if (matches = request.url.match("^/images/(.*)")) {
    var path = process.cwd()+"/images/"+matches[1];
    fs.readFile(path, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        log_error(error);
      } else {
        response.end(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    response.end(page);
  }
});
http_server.listen(port, function() {
  log_comment("server listening (port "+port+")");
});
var page = undefined;
fs.readFile("htmlfilename",function(error,data){
  if(error){
    log_comment(error);
  }
  else{
     page=data;
  }
});
// web socket functions
var websocket_server = new websocket({
  httpServer: http_server
});
websocket_server.on("request", function(request) {
  log_comment("new request ("+request.origin+")");

  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  log_comment("new connection ("+connection.remoteAddress+")");

  webrtc_clients.push(connection);
  connection.id = webrtc_clients.length-1;

  connection.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.type === "utf8") {
      log_comment("got message "+message.utf8Data);

      var signal = undefined;
      try { signal = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data); } catch(e) { };
      if (signal) {
        if (signal.type === "join" && signal.token !== undefined) {
          try {
            if (webrtc_discussions[signal.token] === undefined) {
              webrtc_discussions[signal.token] = {};
            }
          } catch(e) { };
          try {
            webrtc_discussions[signal.token][connection.id] = true;
          } catch(e) { };
        } else if (signal.token !== undefined) {
          try {
            Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[signal.token]).forEach(function(id) {
              if (id != connection.id) {
                webrtc_clients[id].send(message.utf8Data, log_error);
              }
            });
          } catch(e) { };
        } else {
          log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
        }
      } else {
        log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
      }
    }
  });

  connection.on("close", function(connection) {
    log_comment("connection closed ("+connection.remoteAddress+")");    
    Object.keys(webrtc_discussions).forEach(function(token) {
      Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[token]).forEach(function(id) {
        if (id === connection.id) {
          delete webrtc_discussions[token][id];
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

// utility functions
function log_error(error) {
  if (error !== "Connection closed" && error !== undefined) {
    log_comment("ERROR: "+error);
  }
}
function log_comment(comment) {
  console.log((new Date())+" "+comment);
}
```

Comment: Your code is way too long for someone to spend time on it to fix it. Please try to be more concise, write what you already tried and what is the exact issue. This way other users can more easily help you.

Comment: Do you get any error(s) in the console? Also, is this code from a book, an online tutorial, or a repository by any chance?

Comment: Thanks@AdrianBer, I removed the code which is not necessary,yeah @jason i wrote it from a book **getting start with webrtc by rob manson**,i did not get issues in console,my issue is remote peer video is not getting streamed in 1st peer's remote video element.

Comment: I would find some other WebRTC sample code and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Thanks @Jason for helping me!!

Comment: did you find any solution?